# Sharing SSH Keys across multiple hosts

Tags: ssh, distributed-computing, ssh-keys, amazon-kms

I am building a service that is distributed across multiple machines that logs into other target machines and does an action (write to a file, run a shell script, etc.).

Currently, I have this service configured to use username and password as a form of authentication for ssh-ing to the target machines, but it requires some additional bootstrapping on the target machine to get it working. I want to move to a public/private key authentication model.

My question is, since this service is distributed across multiple hosts, is it bad practice to store the private key in a secure location (say using AWS KMS or some similar service), and have each of my machines read from that secured location, or should I have a private key for each of my machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having all of your machines get the ssh keys from a central location is not inherently worse than their all getting their username and password from a central location.  However, the connection over which they get the ssh keys should be secure, which may mean that you have to have at least one key - the one that gets to your central location - stored locally on each machine.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow you.

Are you saying each machine should expect that there is a key stored locally, and if there isn't it should retrieve it from the centralized secure location?

Comment: I'm saying the keys for access to what you refer to as "target" machines would be stored in the central location, but the machines would still need to be able to access the central location.  Thus you still need to store one key or password of some sort on each machine, but you don't need to store a whole bunch of them even if you're accessing a whole bunch of target machines.

Answer (score 2):

I would answer that it's better to have a private key for each machine.

This way if a private key gets pilfered, only one machine is compromised, instead of all of them.

Additionally, you only need to keep the private key protected. Public keys are, by definition, public. Feel free to post your public key on Twitter, if that fancies you. It will have zero impact.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think I would have to protect the public ones. I'm not that familiar with asymmetric encryption, can you have different private keys associated with the same public key?

Comment: No. A private key is always associated with exactly one public key. And vice versa.

Comment: Ah ha. I'm not sure that this would be the approach I want then, I need that public key to be shared so that it is easy to distribute it to the target machines my farm will be logging into.

This presents an interesting trade-off then.

Comment: Well, you can give the target machines all of the public keys. But yes, it's an isolation/manageability tradeoff. You could also have a set of keypairs that's not 1-1 mapped to the clients, but still gives some isolation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use blockchain-based decentralized PKI
system EMCSSH: http://emercoin.com/EMCSSH

*DISCLAIMER:
I'm author of this system, will answer to any questions*